# What is a Latin phrase expressing the same idea as the English phrase "I know, right?"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In English, the phrase "I know, right?" Is a rhetorical question used to indicate that the speaker is in full agreement with the statement just made by a conversational partner. E.g.:

> Speaker 1: Latin Stack Exchange is a great resource for people with ancient language questions.

> Speaker 2: I know, right?

Is there a similar phrase used in conversational Latin? Looking for examples/suggestions for any era of Latin; please indicate which era(s) your answer applies to.

Comment: Is "I know, right" substantially different from "I agree" or "Indeed" or the many other similar phrases? I'm not sure if you're looking for a general statement to indicate agreement or something that matches your chosen phrase specifically in some respect. If you mean the latter, can you elaborate on what aspects of a Latin phrase are most important?

Comment: I think the meaning is the same but the level of formality is different. "I agree" works in just about any circumstance, while "I know, right" might raise eyebrows if it was used in a congressional hearing or other place of high formality. So I guess in what I'm wondering is, is there a Latin phrase that expresses the idea of agreement in a very informal way?

Comment: I don't know if that's what you asked, but the verb "teneo" is a synonym for "to know"  Trop.
      1. In gen., to hold, contain in the mind, to conceive, comprehend, know (syn.: 
        “percipio, intellego): nunc ego teneo, nunc scio, Quid sit hoc negotii,” Plaut. Capt. 3, 5, 39: tenes Quorsum haec tendant quae loquor, id. Ps. 1, 2, 81: 
        “tenes, quid dicam?” Ter. Heaut. 4, 3, 22
        “teneo,” I understand, id. And. 1, 1, 59

Comment: This seems like a good answer to me.